# Why i can't change value of ObservableCollection item?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, observablecollection

Maybe it's a silly question, but. I cannot change value of item in ObservableCollection. Why?

For an example, i have this class:

```
public class Foo : ReactiveObject
{
    public Foo(int a)
    {
        A = a;
    }
    
    [Reactive]
    public int A { get; set; }
}
```

I am initializing it like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos = new ObservableCollection<Foo>
{
    new Foo(0),
    new Foo(1),
    new Foo(2)
};
```

Then, somewhere in my code, i want to do this:

```
SomeCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => 
{
    Foos.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Count > 0).A++;
}

// somewhere later

this.WhenAnyValue(_ => _.Value)
    .InvokeCommand(SomeCommand);
```

The fact is, when command invoking, i can see that `Foos` is changing, and the item's `A` is changing, but when code exits out of command, the `A` is the same as at the beginning and the `Foos` containing only 0, 1 and 2. Why does this happen and how can i fix it? May be i need another type of collection to store items that i want to update each time?

Comment: Does you use ObservableCollection notifications somewhere? Main question why do you use ObservableCollection?

Comment: @kanils_ yea i use its notifications in code, that's why i need some type of collection that can send states